# Grid Column Has Delayed Resize on Overflow

Tags: html, css

I have a 2-by-2 CSS grid that fills the browser viewport using fixed positioning. It looks like this:

```
-----------------
| |xxxxxxxxxxxxx|
-----------------
|x|             |
|x|             |
|x|             |
|x|             |
-----------------
```

The top row and left column each meant to fit their content and have size `auto`. The bottom row and right column are each meant to consume any remaining space and have size `1fr`.

The northeast and southwest cells, which are filled with Xs in the illustration, are each scrollable flex parents. They contain an arbitrary number of child elements, and this number may change dynamically. I set the `overflow` property of each to `auto` and style the scrollbars using these rulesets:

```css
.scrollable::-webkit-scrollbar {
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
}

.scrollable::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: darkgray;
}

.scrollable::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: #666666;
}
```

When I load the page in Chrome on macOS, the scrollbar is overlaid on the content of the southwest cell. Then when I resize the browser window, the left column expands to accommodate the scrollbar (which was already showing as an overlay), and it shifts to the right of the content.

I'd prefer the scrollbar not to overlay the content at all, and I'd really like to eliminate the layout shift on an unrelated resize event. Do you know how I might achieve these goals?

This [Codepen](https://codepen.io/twodee/pen/jOQrbEo) is a minimal reproducible example. However, it doesn't behave consistently for me. When I reload the page, sometimes the scrollbar is overlaid and sometimes the column is already wide enough for the scrollbar to appear right of the content. I see the bad overlay and sizing more consistently on this [standalone page](https://twodee.org/forothers/bad-grid.html).

Answer (score 0):

To prevent this, the grid needs to update its dimensions and take the scrollbar into account. Another question is how to do it with css only. It occurred to me to apply `animation` for `grid-template-columns`, and it seems to work:

```css
* {
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

#grid {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr;
  animation: grid 200ms;
}

@keyframes grid {
  to {
    grid-template-columns: auto 2fr;
  }
}

#nw {
  background-color: green;
}

.scrollable {
  display: flex;
}

#ne {
  background-color: red;
  flex-direction: row;
  overflow-x: auto;
}

#sw {
  background-color: yellow;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow-y: auto;
  scrollbar-color: darkgray #666666;
  scrollbar-width: thick;
}

#se {
  background-color: blue;
}

.box {
  width: 4em;
  height: 4em;
  margin: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: black;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

.scrollable::-webkit-scrollbar {
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
}

.scrollable::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: darkgray;
}

.scrollable::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: #666666;
}
```

```html
<div id="grid">
  <div id="nw"></div>
  <div id="ne" class="scrollable">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="sw" class="scrollable">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="se"></div>
</div>
```

---

If you want to do it with javascript:

```js
setTimeout(() => grid.style.gridTemplateColumns = 'auto 2fr', 200)
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

#grid {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr;
  grid-template-columns: auto 1fr;
}

#nw {
  background-color: green;
}

.scrollable {
  display: flex;
}

#ne {
  background-color: red;
  flex-direction: row;
  overflow-x: auto;
}

#sw {
  background-color: yellow;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow-y: auto;
  scrollbar-color: darkgray #666666;
  scrollbar-width: thick;
}

#se {
  background-color: blue;
}

.box {
  width: 4em;
  height: 4em;
  margin: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: black;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

.scrollable::-webkit-scrollbar {
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
}

.scrollable::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: darkgray;
}

.scrollable::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: #666666;
}
```

```html
<div id="grid">
  <div id="nw"></div>
  <div id="ne" class="scrollable">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="sw" class="scrollable">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="se"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: The CSS approach feels a little indirect. Is there a way to trigger the recalculation in JavaScript? I tried calling `getBoundingClientRect`, which is supposed to trigger a reflow, but that had no effect.

Comment: Why use javascript when it works without it?

Comment: One, because the semantics are wrong. (But so are the apparent JavaScripter triggers.) Two, I have dynamic content, so I'd either have to make the animation repeat forever or restart the animation with JavaScript.

Comment: I added a javascript solution to the answer